# Get week day name in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I get the name of the day in Ruby?

For eg. something like that:

```ruby
a = Date.today
a.day_name
# => Tuesday
```

the only thing I could find was `.wday` but that only returns for the number of the day in the week

```ruby
a.wday
# => 2
```

Comment: How about `a.strftime("%A")`? Check [this](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) for more!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```ruby
Time.now.strftime("%A")
# => "Tuesday"
```

or

```ruby
Date.today.strftime("%A")
# => "Tuesday"
```

```
Weekday:
  %A - The full weekday name (``Sunday'')
          %^A  uppercased (``SUNDAY'')
  %a - The abbreviated name (``Sun'')
          %^a  uppercased (``SUN'')
```

Source: [strftime @ apidock.com](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

Answer (score 13):

Since the OP references `Date.today`, we can assume the presence of `Date` (Rails, not pure Ruby), so a simpler solution would be to use the `Date::DAYNAMES` array:

```
Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday]
```

Comment: Use `I18n.translate("date.day_names")[Date.today.wday]` if you need translated names in Rails.