# Get array of next 7 days name from today in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Hi I want to form an array of next 7 days from today,
Example: Suppose today is Sunday so result should be

```
["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday",'Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a nice little one liner to do what you want.

```rb
(0..6).map{ |n| (Date.today+n).strftime("%A")}
```

Assuming today is Saturday, that will produce:

```rb
["Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
```

Quick explanation of each part:
`(0..6)` creates an array of numbers: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

`.map { |n| ... }` is a function called on the above array that takes each element in one at a time as `n`.

`(Date.today+n)` is an object that represents today's day (based on your system clock). It lets you add a number to it to offset the date, which creates a new object.

And finally `.strftime("%A")}` is called on the offset date object to produce a string from the date object. The `"%A"` is a format directive for string day of the week.

Comment: You can also use `7.times` instead of the range.

Answer (score 7):

```
require 'date'

Date::DAYNAMES.rotate(Date.today.wday)
  #=> ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
  #    "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

because `Date.today.wday #=> 0` (Sunday). If today were Tuesday, `Date.today.wday #=> 2`, so

```
Date::DAYNAMES.rotate(2)
  #=> ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday",
  #    "Sunday", "Monday"]
```

See [Array#rotate](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate).

Answer (score 6):

Using Ruby on Rails you do like that:

```
today = DateTime.now
(today..(today + 7.days)).map { |date| date.strftime("%A") }

=> ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

You will controll next days size modifying `7.days` part.

> [Answer supported from this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365439/get-name-of-the-day/29365496)

Comment: Looks like we both had the same idea :)

Comment: haha Yeah! In the same time. But your answer is more complete. Great!

Answer (score 1):

Code

```
require 'date'
p (Date.today..Date.today+7).map{|d|d.strftime("%A")}
```

Output

```
["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```